# Remote Debugging in Qt Trought Telnet. Is It possible?

Tags: qt, ssh, remote-debugging

I have some device in MIPS architecture, on this device unfortunately wasn't instal any server ssh, but **telnet daemon** is present. I try connect to this device in goal remote debbuging but I do not can connect. Also If I try test connect.
**So it is possible to remote debugging in Qt trought Telnet** ? Whether this function is only reserved for SSH server ?

[image]